# Linear Algebra and differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

What will be the matrix A if I want to express the following differential equation in the form Ay=0?
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by that?  What is the relation between the $y$ of your differential equation and the $y$ of $Ay=0$?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin First I guessed A to be $[\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+1]$ but then the solution space has dimensionality=2 and basis is cosx and sinx. So I concluded that there should be a different A.

Comment: @RobertIsrael the two y's are same matrices

Comment: No, the $y$ in the differential equation is a scalar function.  Are you thinking of $A = D^2+I$ as a linear operator on a space of functions?  But it's an infinite-dimensional space, so $A$ is not a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce an auxiliary function $u=y'$. You can then rewrite the second-order equation as the first-order system $$u'=-y \\ y'=u.$$ I hope that you know how to construct the matrix form of this system.